# Checkbox in jsp code at IE11

Tags: html, jsp, internet-explorer-11

I have a site in `jsp` code. Recently we updated all our explorer browsers to version 11 from 8. When I checked if there are new problems i saw that in some places where I have checkboxes there are just text inputs, when i press inspect element I saw:

```
<input style="type:checkbox" type="text">
```

the code is

```
<yac:abc ... type="checkbox">
```

I added the site to the Compatibility view Settings.
The really weird thing is that I tried to check in ie8 and I saw that it's good and when I press **f12** it shows a good checkbox. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the old .jsp pages may not be supported by the new Internet Explorer.

Try adding the site to the Compatibility view Settings.

By choosing: Setting -> Compatibility view Settings -> Add 
(Note: That you need to specify the website to add)